# Vertically position an image inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem I'd like some help with. Thankfully my code can be flexible, so I'll just give some generic markup.

My major limitation (due to the way I am retrieving the information from a database) is that the images CANNOT be background images, otherwise this would be easy.

I simply want an image to change when I hover over it. I have made an image twice as high as I need it - half colour, half black and white. The idea is, the image is exactly the same (a person) - but when you hover over it - you see the colour version.

I have constructed my 'hover' image 200 pixels wide, and 400 pixels high. It is marked up very simply:

```
<div class='staff_profile'>
     <h3>Staff Title</h3>
     <div class='staff_image'>
         <img src='.....' alt='....' />
     </div>
</div>
```

So I am figuring I need something like:

```
.staff_image {
   float: left;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

The trouble is - using this, the 400px high image displays by default in the centre of that staff_image div - so I see half the black and white photo, and half the colour.

I am going to be using jQuery to do the hover - so just need some CSS tips on what properties I need to use to:

1. Have the image display at the very top
2. Have the image display from halfway down

Everything I try with padding and margin seems to push all content down, and doesn't move the actual picture inside at all. I basically need to know how to maneuver an image that is too tall for a fixed height div around WITHIN that div. And none of the answers I can find here seem to help. There are lots of them on centering an image - but centering is NOT what I want to do - it's the opposite! :)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/xqxSK/

```
<div class='staff_profile'>
     <h3>Staff Title</h3>
     <div class='staff_image'>
         <img src='http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6' />
     </div>
</div>

.staff_image {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}
.staff_image img {
    position: relative;
}

.staff_image:hover img {
   top: -200px;
}
```

I'm using CSS instead of jquery for the hover. This is a better approach, since it works better on touchscreen devices.

Comment: Thanks - this is correct. Actually - although this works on a blank page, it still doesn't on my own page. Which is fine - it just means that something else is interfering - I'll be able to find that. Thanks!